# implement search filters in java

Tags: mysql, search, filter, lucene, cassandra

We need to implement a search filter (Net-log like) for my social networking site against user profile, filters on profile include age range, gender and interests

we have approx 1M profiles running on MySQL, MySQL doesn't seems the right option to implement such filters so we are looking on Cassandra as well,

So what is the best way to implement such filter, The result need to be very quick

e.g. age = 18 - 24 and gender = male and interest = Football

Age in Date, Gender and interests are varchar

EDITED:
 
Let me rephrase the problem, How can I get fastest result of any type of search.
It could be on the bases of profile name, or any other profile thing on 1M profile records.

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't MySQL seem like the right option? Have you found that it's too slow?

Comment: like statement in mysql is over killing

Comment: Who said anything about `like`?

Comment: I tried a simple select on interest with like %Football% and results of the query took a long time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would serve your project well to make an underlying SQL change. You might want to consider changing the Interest column from a free-input field (varchar) to a tag (Many-to-many on an additional table, for example).

You used the example of `Football` and having a `like` operator on it. If you changed it to a tag, then you will have an initial structural problem of deciding where to place:

```
football
Football
American Football
Australian-rules football
```

But once you have done so, the tags will help your select statement go much faster.

Without this change, you will be pushing your data management problem from a database (which is equipped to handle it) to Java (which might not be).

Comment: you are right regarding tag but the problem will still be there even for age and gender search. The normal select query even a count on large table take a long time.

Comment: Have you tried birthday between '1987-06-17' and '1993-06-17'? The SQL engine is equipped to optimize it. What about making gender a nullable boolean Male (so that true means Male, false means female, and null means didn't respond)? Bear in mind that the SQL engine will weed out unwanted records very quickly and obtain the desired subset, while this is harder to do in Java (where you don't know the records until you select the records). Basic SQL optimization will buy you a lot with no programming changes, so think first about indexes, no wildcards, and using the built-in EXPLAIN instruction.

Answer (score 0):

It may make some sense to try to optimize your query (there may at least be some things that you can do). It sounds like you have a large database, and if you are returning a large result set and filtering the results with java, you may get performance issues because of all of the data kept in cache.

If this is the case, one thing that you could try is looking into caching the results, outside of the database and reading from that. This is something that [Hibernate does very well](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/37-introduction-to-hibernate-caching-1.html), but you could implement your own version if needed. If this is something that you are interested in, [Memcached](http://memcached.org/), is a good starting place.

I just noticed this for MySQL. I do not know how efficient it is but they have some build in [full text searching functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html), that may help speed things up.

Comment: We do not want to filter results in java like by running loop on 1M records and we have hibernate and memcached on our backend servers.

Comment: Good, I didnt know your setup and I figured that is a good place to start.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time what keywords people will search for, or have an idea of what is commonly used? You could look into adding tags or some form of indexing some of the text that will be searched on, so all you have to do is search on the tags, if there is a tag for what the user is looking for.  The tagging could be done when the text is saved so there wouldn't be a real performance loss.